# How to have fixed size in funnel chart but dynamic hover text?

Tags: r, hover, plotly, r-plotly

I am trying to have a funnel chart using R.

The issue is numbers are skewed and they won't have a uniform representation. However, we want to show the flow. So how can I make a funnel chart in R where the size of the funnel is fixed but the text is dynamic and coming from a dataframe column.

**See Source Code Example:** https://plot.ly/r/funnel-charts/

```
requiredPackages <- c("plotly")

ipak <- function(pkg){
  new.pkg <- pkg[!(pkg %in% installed.packages()[, "Package"])]
  if (length(new.pkg))
    install.packages(new.pkg, dependencies = TRUE)
  sapply(pkg, require, character.only = TRUE)
}

ipak(requiredPackages)

p <- plot_ly(
  type = "funnelarea",
  values = c(5, 4, 3, 2, 1),
  text = c("The 1st","The 2nd", "The 3rd", "The 4th", "The 5th"),
  marker = list(colors = c("deepskyblue", "lightsalmon", "tan", "teal", "silver"),
                line = list(color = c("wheat", "wheat", "blue", "wheat", "wheat"), 
  width = c(0, 1, 5, 0, 4))),
  textfont = list(family = "Old Standard TT, serif", size = 13, color = "black"),
  opacity = 0.65)

p
```

#### Result

[image]

Comment: Can you clarify exactly what you are to do? You state "The issue is numbers are skewed and they won't have a uniform representation", it is not quite clear what you want to do.

Comment: I want to show the funnel chart like above but on hover I want to show different text . The tunnel is just to represent the shapes but hover will show the actual values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sub>***I want to show the funnel chart like above; but on hover I want to show different text. The tunnel is just to represent the shapes but hover will show the actual values.***</sub>

Based on the above comment of OP, I am guessing they want the hoverinfo to pick its text from this vector of values `c(5,4,3,2,1)`.

The first graph/solution works for that matter:

```
library(plotly)

plot_ly(
  type = "funnelarea",
  values = c(5, 4, 3, 2, 1),
  text = c("The 1st","The 2nd", "The 3rd", "The 4th", "The 5th"),
  marker = list(colors = c("deepskyblue", "lightsalmon", "tan", "teal", "silver"),
                line = list(color = c("wheat", "wheat", "blue", "wheat", "wheat"),
  width = c(0, 1, 5, 0, 4))),
  textfont = list(family = "Old Standard TT, serif", size = 13, color = "black"),
  opacity = 0.65,
  hovertemplate = '%{value}<extra></extra>')
```

It's possible to add more text/values. Below is an example of that. You can read more here: https://plot.ly/r/hover-text-and-formatting/

```r
plot_ly(
  type = "funnelarea",
  values = c(5, 4, 3, 2, 1),
  text = c("The 1st","The 2nd", "The 3rd", "The 4th", "The 5th"),
  marker = list(colors = c("deepskyblue", "lightsalmon", "tan", "teal", "silver"),
                line = list(color = c("wheat", "wheat", "blue", "wheat", "wheat"), 
  width = c(0, 1, 5, 0, 4))),
  textfont = list(family = "Old Standard TT, serif", size = 13, color = "black"),
  opacity = 0.65,
  hovertemplate = paste('%{value}<extra></extra>' ,
                        '%{text}<extra></extra>'))
```

Comment: ***N.B.*** Percentages are missing from the plots above cause I downsized the picture to be fitted into my post here. Those percentages are in the actual plot.